# How can I do a logical test involving the return value of a piped command while taking advantage of short-circuiting?

Tags: bash

Here is the code I'm trying to get right, but I know that it is logically incorrect, as the `!` binds only to the first test.

```
# if Vim was compiled in the same month, skip.
if ! [[ -f /usr/local/bin/vim ]] && /usr/local/bin/vim --version | grep "compiled $(date +%b) [0-9]{1,2} $(date +%Y) " -
```

The reason that I know it is logically wrong is:

```
$ if ! [[ a == b ]] && [[ c == c ]]; then echo yy; fi
yy

$ if ! [[ a == a ]] && [[ a == c ]]; then echo yy; fi

$
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is to use the curlies:

```
$ if ! { [[ a == a ]] && [[ a == c ]]; }; then echo yy; fi
yy
```

I wonder if there is anything more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ a != a ]] || [[ a != c ]]; then echo yy; fi
```

or:

```
if ! /usr/local/bin/vim --version 2> /dev/null | grep "compiled ...
```

Comment: Also: `[[ ( a != a ) || ( a != c ) ]]; then echo yy; fi`

Comment: Ah, but you see, I needed the curlies, because the pass/fail condition from the piped command can't be stuffed into the `[[` test! Anyway your second example is pretty good as it implicitly will fail if the executable is missing.